# Cant figure out where I am making mistake

Tags: ruby

Issue:
def average_of_three(num1, num2, num3)​

```
  puts "Enter first number"
  num1= gets.to_i

  puts "Enter second number"
  num2 = gets.to_i

  puts "Enter third number"
  num3 = gets.to_i

  avg=0

  avg = (num1 +num2 + num3 )/3
  puts "your average is#{avg}"
end
```

Solution:
I was missing the following statement  :

```
average_of_three(10, 20, 30)
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This code should work if you call that method, but the method doesn't need arguments. Those variables are declared locally anyway.

Right now you'd do:

```
average_of_three(0, 0, 0)
```

Where the initial values don't matter as you ignore them anyway. They could be `:zero` or `"Who cares!"` just the same.

This isn't very Ruby code though. When writing Ruby think first in terms of data structures.

For example, to get three values:

```
def get_n(n = 3)
  n.times.map do |i|
    print "Enter number #{i+1}: "
    gets.to_i
  end
end
```

This asks a series of questions and stores the result in an array, that's what [`map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) does.

Now you can average those:

```
def average(values)
  return unless (values.any?)

  values.sum / values.length
end
```

This has a *guard clause* where it won't execute unless there's at least one value. Then it calls [`sum`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-sum), which not surprisingly adds up all the values. Divide by the length and you're done.

So you'd tie this all together with:

```
values = get_n

puts "Average is: #{average(values)}"
```

Note: In Ruby when you divide an integer by an integer you always get an integer. This means the values get rounded. If you'd prefer to have fractional results you can switch the input converter from `.to_i` to `.to_f`. That change will cause floats to flow through the rest of the code.

Comment: These days, I prefer using `fdiv` to tacking a `to_f` onto everything.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev How so?

Comment: Looks cleaner and more intention-revealing, I guess. Directly says "I want to get a float out of this" rather than relying on the default behavior of whatever type we happen to receive.